# Substituting values from MySQL fields when printing in PHP

Tags: php, variables, date, while-loop

I have a database table with columns 'name' (of an event) and 'day' (in full, so: 'Monday, 'Tuesday' etc). In a `while` loop displaying an event followed by its day in brackets is quite straightforward.

Is there a way to systematically substitute each day for the date that that day falls on next? So Monday would be 11 Jun, Tuesday would be 12 Jun, etc.

I've tried something along these lines, but the variable stays the same for each row of 'name' - retrospectively this makes sense.

```
$today = date("l");
$todays_date = date("j M");

if ($row['day'] == $today) {
    $date = $todays_date;
    }

else if (day == date("l", strotime("+1 day")) {
    $date = date("j M", strotime("+1 day"));
    }

echo "<option>" . $row['name'] . " (" . $date . ")</option>";
```

**EDIT**

Here's what I now have:

```
function getClubs() {
connect();

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$day = date("l");
$time = date("G");

if ($time >= 21) {
    $day = date('l', strtotime($day .' +1 day'));
    }


if ($day == Monday) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Tuesday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Wednesday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Thursday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Friday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Saturday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY')";
    }

else if ($day == Sunday) {
    $query = "SELECT name FROM nights WHERE city = 'Cambridge' ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY')";
    }


    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $items = array();

    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
//          $items[] = array($row['name']);

$day = $row['day'];

function getDateString($day){
    if (date("l")==$day){
        return date("j M");
    }
    else {
        $date = strtotime("next $day");
        return date("j M",$date);
    }
}

            echo "<option>" . $row['name'] . " (" . getDateString($row['day']) . ")</option>";

            }         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/strtotime) to get this, for example:

```
$date = strtotime('next tuesday');
```

You would then use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to convert it to a string (such as 12 Jun):

```
date("j M",$date);
```

Also if the event is today and you want it to display the current date you'd add some checking code, so all together as a function:

```
function getDateString($day){
    if (date("l")==$day){
       return date("j M");
    } else {
       $date = strtotime("next $day");
       return date("j M",$date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How does this fit with my code? Does it not need to be some sort of an array to prevent it giving the same value for every event that is printed into the dropdown?

Comment: When you loop through all your dates, in your echo statement you'd just change it to this: `echo "<option>" . $row['name'] . " (" . getDateString($row['name']) . ")</option>";`

Comment: That makes sense, thanks very much. Just one thing - would it not be getDateString($row['day'])?

Comment: Apologies you are right, it should be `$row['day']`. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Closest I've been to solving this all day! It works for the first event but it doesn't load any more, or the rest of the page. I've added my current code to my main post as an edit.

Comment: None of your queries are returning the 'day' column! (except Monday which returns `*` aka everything). You should change the start of all your queries to `SELECT name, day FROM nights`. ALSO move the getDateString function outside of your getClubs function, so maybe just above getClubs.

Comment: Took the function out of getClubs and it works perfectly. Thanks very much!

Comment: One final thing (promise) - is there a way to refer to the variables outside of the while loop? I'd like to print them elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Well that question has many answers. The simplest way is to create an array at the top of your file, for instance put `$items = array();` as the first line of your PHP code. Then in the while loop you add items to that array, like `array_push($items, $row['name'])`. The array called `$items` will be available everywhere in that file.

Answer (score 0):

This places the date in `$dayDates` if `$beginDate` is a monday. Is this what you are looking for?

```
$daysoftheweek = array(0 => 1);

while($beginDate <= $endDate)
{
    if(in_array(date('N', $beginDate), $daysOfTheWeek))
    {
        $dayDates[] = date('Y-m-d', $beginDate);
    }

    $beginDate = strtotime("+1 day", $beginDate);
}
```